# ejb look fails from swing client using kerberos ticket

Tags: swing, ejb, kerberos, jaas, ejb-2.x

I am getting teh following error when trying to look up ejb from Java swing client

2013-09-04 16:19:04,595 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor] (WorkerThread#0[10.24.0.93:61667]) Error in Security Interceptor
java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication exception, principal=null
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.checkSecurityContext(SecurityInterceptor.java:321)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:243)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invokeHome(SecurityInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invokeHome(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invokeHome(LogInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invokeHome(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvokeHome(SessionContainer.java:639)
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1046)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.invocation.unified.server.UnifiedInvoker.invoke(UnifiedInvoker.java:232)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the source. JBoss version? Is it a stand-alone client? What is your authentication setup?

Comment: I am using Jboss 5.1.0 AS and ejb 2 look up. I am using kerberos ticket to authenticate both at client and server side. The client authentication is fine but not able to pass the kerberos ticket along with the ejb look, thats where it fails. basically I am calling Subject.doAs(s, lv); after the authentication is complete at client side. But it seems the subject is not passed to the server